# print parts of data results while queries are still working

Tags: mysql, mongodb, postgresql, cassandra, nosql

I was wondering if it's possible in some way to display parts of the result while still fetching data? This is for big queries where the datasets are large.

Is this possible in mysql or postgresql, or perhaps nosql databases?

Let's say i want to fetch 100 rows of tables with some joins, which would take about 50-60 seconds to fetch all data, can i somehow display 1 result at a time?

so while still fetching data, print what it already got.

Have a nice day all!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to fetch 10 times by 10 results and load them via ajax